# Create blog page only to see one category

Tags: categories

I'm doing a Wordpress blog. The **blog** page has a submenu in which appear the categories of the posts and the idea is, when I click in one category, it displays the posts that are of that category.

So the problem is, I have to create a new page and pass url parameters to know which category was selected? What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the function `<?php echo get_category_link( $category_id ); ?>` I can access to the category pages of the blog.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_link/

> Retrieve category link URL.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the category url is *www.homepage.com/category/slug-of-the-category/*. You can find all categories and their url under **Posts -> Categories** in  the backend of WordPress.
So you don't have to create a page, because the pages already exist.